# Cumulative sum but conditionally excluding earlier rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'val_a': [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1],
  'val_b': [3, np.nan, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, np.nan, 0],
  'quantity': [1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2]
})
```

It looks like this:

```
|    |   val_a |   val_b |   quantity |
|---:|--------:|--------:|-----------:|
|  0 |       3 |       3 |          1 |
|  1 |       3 |     nan |          4 |
|  2 |       3 |       2 |          2 |
|  3 |       2 |       2 |          8 |
|  4 |       2 |       2 |          5 |
|  5 |       2 |       0 |          7 |
|  6 |       1 |       1 |          1 |
|  7 |       1 |     nan |          4 |
|  8 |       1 |       0 |          2 |
```

It is ordered by `val_a`. I'd like to take a cumulative sum for the total `quantity` for each `val_a`. So:

```py
df.groupby('val_a', sort=False).sum().cumsum().drop(columns='val_b')
```

which gives

```
|   val_a |   quantity |
|--------:|-----------:|
|       3 |          7 |
|       2 |         27 |
|       1 |         34 |
```

*However*, here's the tricky part.

I'd like to exclude rows such that the value of `val_b` is greater than the key `val_a`. I'll clarify with an example:

- when calculating the total for when `val_a` is `3`, none of the rows have `val_b` greater than `val_a`. So the cumulative total for when `val_a` is `3` is `7`;
- when calculating the total for when `val_a` is `2`, then row 0 has `val_b` greater than `2`. That row has `quantity` 1. So, excluding that row, the cumulative total for when `val_a` is `2` is `27 - 1`, i.e. `26`;
- when calculating the total for when `val_a` is `1`, then rows 0, 2, 3, 4 have `val_b` greater than `1`,. That row has `quantity` 1. So, excluding that row, the cumulative total for when `val_a` is `1` is `34 - 1 - 2 - 8 - 5`, i.e. `18`;

Here's the desired output:

```
|   val_a |   quantity |
|--------:|-----------:|
|       3 |          7 |
|       2 |         26 |
|       1 |         18 |
```

Comment: Something I don't get in your logic: *So the cumulative total for when val_a is 3 is 7;* and yet in your final dataframe, 7 is matched to val_a of 1. Is the order of val_a in the original dataframe not important? Would you expect the same result if you sort first by val_a?

Comment: ooh, that's a good point, I'll fix it

Comment: @mozway have updated (I'd forgotten to put `sort=False` in `groupby`)

Comment: OK thanks, then I have a proposition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of NumPy:

```
# sum without conditions
raw_sum = df.groupby("val_a", sort=False).quantity.sum().cumsum()

# comparing each `val_b` against each unique `val_a` via `gt.outer`
sub_mask = np.greater.outer(df.val_b.to_numpy(), df.val_a.unique())

# selecting values to subtract from `quantity` and summing per `val_a`
to_sub = (sub_mask * df.quantity.to_numpy()[:, np.newaxis]).sum(axis=0)

# subtracting from the raw sum
result = raw_sum - to_sub
```

to get

```
>>> result.reset_index()

   val_a  quantity
0      3         7
1      2        26
2      1        18
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```py
# Your initial dataframe
group_df = (
    df.groupby("val_a").sum().cumsum().drop(columns="val_b").reset_index(drop=False)
)

# Pairing val_a and inverse index number
pairs = {
    i: j - 1
    for i, j in zip(group_df["val_a"].values, reversed(group_df["val_a"].values))
}

# Iterating according to the logic of your example
for i, j in pairs.items():
    group_df.loc[j, "quantity"] = (
        group_df.loc[j, "quantity"] - df.loc[df["val_b"] > i, "quantity"].sum()
    )

# Your desired output
print(group_df)
   val_a  quantity
0      1         7
1      2        26
2      3        18
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to calculate the correction factor:

```
df2 = df.set_index('val_a')
def cond_sub(s):
    return df2.loc[:s.name][(df2.loc[:s.name]['val_b']>s.name)]['quantity'].sum()
```

output:

```
1    16
2     1
3     0
```

You can then combine it with your original function:

```
(df.groupby('val_a', sort=False).sum().cumsum().drop(columns='val_b')['quantity']
-df.groupby('val_a', sort=False).sum().apply(cond_sub, axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
3     7
2    26
1    18
```